# Jquery Grid with random alpha effect

Tags: jquery, grid, tiles, alpha

Ok, I just need a light here.

I want to make just a visual effect like the one on the image of the smiles at the right side this website.

http://iitweb.com/

Basically a grid tile effect with random alpha that goes on and off continuosly over the image. Any ideas what could I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may be a little late for you but it might help anyone looking for the same thing.

This would be my first approach:

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://profile-b-ord.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ash3/27537_111050195577875_7540_q.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc7/369585_100004094319706_2126721826_q.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://vialibrepl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/THUNDERCATS-50x50.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.brainzum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Inspector-Gadget-Go-Go-Gadget-Collection1-50x50.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://spe.fotolog.com/photo/46/54/51/_melizita/Homer_Simpson_1240210329589_t.jpg" alt="" />
```

**JS**

```
function fadeRandomTile()
{
    var tiles = $("img").length;
    var random_tile = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles);
    var $tile = $("img").eq(random_tile);

    if(!$tile.data("alpha"))
    {
        $tile.fadeTo(500, 0.5).data("alpha", true);
    }
    else
    {
        $tile.fadeTo(500, 1).data("alpha", false);
    }
}

setInterval(function(){fadeRandomTile()}, 1000);
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/gEpan/1/